# React + Docker: Failed to resolve import

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, vite

I've been beating my head against a wall here trying to solve this, but I keep getting the following error that I can't resolve whenever I try to yarn add something and then use it:

> PM [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "@mui/x-data-grid" from "src/components/formSubmit.tsx". Does the file exist?

Could I be somehow screwing up my node_modules? I think my docker script is correct, and I've checked that it exists in node_modules on the image, but I still seem to be getting this issue.

My folder structure is:

```
--Myapp
|--frontend
   -node_modules
   -package.json
   -index.html
   - public
   - src
       - App.tsx
       - index.tsx
       - components
          - formsubmit.tsx
   - tsconfig.json
   - vite.config.js
   - vite-env.d.ts
|--compose
   |--local
      |--react
      |--django
|--djangobackend
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  myapp_local_postgres_data: {}
  myapp_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: myapp_local_django
    container_name: myapp_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - '28000:8000'
    command: /start

  react:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/react/Dockerfile
    image: myapp_react
    container_name: myapp_react
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - django
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    ports:
      - 28001:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    command: yarn start
```

Frontend dockerfile:

```
ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=local

FROM node:lts-bookworm-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./frontend/package.json .
#COPY ./frontend/yarn.lock .

COPY ./frontend/src .
COPY ./frontend/public .
COPY ./frontend/vite.config.ts .
COPY ./frontend/vite-env.d.ts .
COPY ./frontend/tsconfig.json .
COPY ./frontend/index.html .

RUN yarn


EXPOSE 3000
CMD yarn dev
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "types": ["vite/client"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import { resolve, dirname } from "node:path";


export default defineConfig({
    // depending on your application, base can also be "/"
    base: '',
    plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), ],
    server: {
        // this ensures that the browser opens upon server start
        open: false,
        // this sets a default port to 3000
        port: 3000,
        host: true,
        strictPort: true,
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        },
        fs: {
            cachedChecks: false
        },
    },
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.10",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.165",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.10",
    "@mui/system": "^5.15.9",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.19.4",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.19",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "jodit": "^4.0.6",
    "jodit-react-ts": "^0.9.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10",
    "vite": "^5.1.3",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "tsc & vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And then I'm just trying to do:

```
import { DataGrid, GridRowsProp, GridColDef } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
```

Comment: If your `node_modules` tree is corrupted, the `volumes:` block as you have it means you will keep using the broken version even if you rebuild the image.  Does deleting the `volumes:` block help (for both of the containers you show; keep it on your databases)?

Comment: @DavidMaze yeah it works when i remove and add it back in the docker-compose. Should I be permanently removing the mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Your `docker-compose.yml` defines a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for [`node_modules`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#loading-from-node_modules-folders) that might be overriding your installed modules with the local empty directory. That can cause issues where dependencies are not found inside the Docker container.

The import statement is looking for `formSubmit.tsx` while your filesystem has `formsubmit.tsx`. Linux, including Docker containers, is case-sensitive, unlike Windows. Make sure the filenames match exactly, including their case.

Your current Dockerfile copies individual files and then runs `yarn` without first copying over `yarn.lock`. That could lead to discrepancies between your local and Docker environments.
Instead:

```
FROM node:lts-bookworm-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and yarn.lock
COPY ./frontend/package.json ./frontend/yarn.lock ./

# Install dependencies
RUN yarn install

# Copy the rest of your frontend application
COPY ./frontend .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

That would make sure your dependencies are installed based on the locked versions from `yarn.lock`, providing a more consistent build between local and Docker environments.

Since you are using [`vite-tsconfig-paths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths), make sure your `tsconfig.json` paths are correctly set up to resolve the module paths as expected.

---

> It works when I remove and add it back in the docker-compose.

If removing the `volumes:` block leads to a working setup, that is a strong indicator that the volume mapping for `node_modules` might be the main problem. That is because Docker volumes persist data across container rebuilds, which can inadvertently cause an outdated or corrupted `node_modules` directory to be reused, leading to the kinds of errors you are experiencing.

Removing and then re-adding the `node_modules` volume in the `docker-compose.yml` temporarily resolves the issue because it forces Docker to use the freshly installed `node_modules` from within the container, rather than the potentially corrupted or mismatched version from the volume.

But... reinstalling dependencies every time you build the Docker image can increase build times, especially for large projects. And if you are actively developing and need to add or update dependencies, not having `node_modules` mapped to the host can make it slightly more cumbersome to manage these changes.

- **For Development:** Consider using a named volume for `node_modules` or directly installing dependencies inside the container without mapping them back to the host. That does allow you to leverage Docker's caching mechanisms, and to avoid reinstalling dependencies unless `package.json` or `yarn.lock` changes.

  ```yaml
  services:
  react:
      volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - myapp_frontend_node_modules:/app/node_modules
  ```

  And declare the named volume at the bottom of your `docker-compose.yml`:

  ```yaml
  volumes:
    myapp_frontend_node_modules:
  ```
- **For Production:** It is generally best practice to omit the `node_modules` volume entirely. Dependencies should be baked into the image during the build process, making sure that the container runs with exactly the dependencies it was tested with.

---

> With that, I'd still need to re-build my docker every time I install something else with yarn, right?

Yes, that is correct. When you make changes to your dependencies by adding or updating packages with `yarn`, you would need to rebuild your Docker image to make sure these changes are reflected inside the container.
That is because the Docker build process involves copying your application code (including `package.json` and `yarn.lock`) into the image and running `yarn install` to fetch the dependencies specified therein. These steps are important to capture the updated state of your dependencies within the Docker environment.

However, there are strategies to minimize the inconvenience and build times associated with this process:

#### 1. **Leveraging Docker caching**:

By structuring your `Dockerfile` to first copy only `package.json` and `yarn.lock`, and then running `yarn install` before copying the rest of your application code, you can take advantage of [Docker's caching mechanism](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/).
Docker will cache the layer where dependencies are installed and will only re-run `yarn install` if `package.json` or `yarn.lock` have changed. That can significantly reduce build times when your dependencies are unchanged, but your application code is being updated.

#### 2. **Development environment considerations**:

For a development environment, you might not want to rebuild the Docker image for every minor change in your dependencies.
Instead, you could:

- **Use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) for `node_modules`** from the host into the container. That way, when you run `yarn add` or `yarn remove` from the host, the changes are directly reflected in the container without a rebuild. However, this approach can introduce inconsistencies between your host and container environments, so it should be used with caution and likely avoided in production scenarios.

#### 3. **Utilizing Docker Compose**:

If you are using [`docker compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), you can streamline the process of rebuilding your image and restarting your container with updated dependencies by using commands like `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` which handle both steps. Docker Compose also supports build-time arguments, which can be useful for customizing builds without altering the `Dockerfile`.

#### 4. **Optimizing Build Context**:

Make sure your [Docker build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) is as small as possible by using a `.dockerignore` file to exclude unnecessary files and directories (such as local `node_modules`) from being sent to the Docker daemon during builds. That can further speed up the build process.

Comment: Thanks! With that I'd still need to re-build my docker every time I install something else with yarn, right?

I still seem to be having issues with that - I installed something new, ran build to copy everything over, but the new item doesnt appear in node_modules in the container, only packages.js

Comment: @Jordan True. I have edited the answer to address your question.